# Событие закрытия окна wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
    #include <wx\wx.h>
class Form :public wxApp
{
   wxFrame*window;

public:

   bool OnInit()
   {
      window = new wxFrame(nullptr, -1, "Form", wxPoint(100, 100), wxSize(840, 640));
      window->Centre(wxBOTH);
      window->Show(true);
      return true;
   }

   ~Form()
   {
      wxMessageBox("Bye", "Info");
   }
};
class Win :public wxApp
{
   wxFrame*window;

public:

   bool OnInit()
   {
      window = new wxFrame(nullptr, -1, "hi", wxPoint(100, 100), wxSize(840, 640));


      window->Centre(wxBOTH);
      window->Show(true);

      Form *form = new  Form();
      form->OnInit();

      return true;
   }
   void form_close()
   {
      wxMessageBox("Form closed", "Info");
   }

};
IMPLEMENT_APP(Win);
```

как отследить закрытие окна Form в Win

Comment: Лайк за wxwidgets

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам надо разобраться какое именно событие вы хотите отследить - закрытие окна (в вашем случае, представленного экземпляром класса [wxFrame](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_frame.html)) или закрытие всего приложения.

Первое имеет тип *wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW* и произойдет при нажатии пользователем на кнопку закрытия или создано программно, после вызова функции [Close/1](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a3e44f4a494fc9ef4346c4fba70c8de0c).

Чтобы его обработать можно воспользоваться таблицей событий или с помощью [wxEvtHandler::Bind<>()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_evt_handler.html#a0f30c8fa5583b4a5f661897d63de3b62), если ваш компилятор умеет задействовать возможности C++11.
Пример:

```
frame->Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, [&](wxCloseEvent& event)
    {
    if ( event.CanVeto())
        {
        if ( wxMessageBox("Уверены что хотите закрыть?",
            "Подтвердите действие",
            wxICON_QUESTION | wxYES_NO) != wxYES )
            {
            event.Veto();
            return;
            }
        }
    event.Skip();//вызовет Destroy/0 по-умолчанию  
    });
```

тоже самое можно сделать и в конструкторе фрейма:

```
    Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, [&](wxCloseEvent& event)
        {
        if ( event.CanVeto())
            {
            if ( wxMessageBox("Уверены что хотите закрыть?",
                "Подтвердите действие",
                wxICON_QUESTION | wxYES_NO) != wxYES )
                {
                event.Veto();
                return;
                }
            }
        event.Skip();  
        });
```

Если про второе, то для выполнения операций при закрытии приложения(оно выполняется автоматически после уничтожения всех окон[речь об обычном GUI приложении]), достаточно перегрузить функцию [OnExit/0](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_app_console.html#a5ee60051c92b0b2933258799626a0485). При неудачном вызове OnInit/0 функция OnExit/0 не вызывается.

Как обычно, подробности вы можете прочесть в документации(она на английском):

1. Про события и их обработку - [Events and Event Handling](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_events.html)
2. Удаление окон - [Window Deletion](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_windowdeletion.html)
3. Приложения wxWidgets - [wxApp](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_app.html)

Советую также обратить внимание на примеры из папки samples - они очень полезны.